# Is it okay to use "taken care" without "of"

Tags: prepositions, verb-forms

Please find the below sentence and let me know whether it is right or wrong.

> Accounting issue is taken care by Joseph.

Comment: **Take care** means "exercise caution, be careful".  **Take care of** means "assume responsibility for"

Answer (score 3):

Your original sentence is awkward and **grammatically incorrect**

> Accounting issue is **taken care** by Joseph

You need to use **taken care of** to show **responsibility**

> **The** accounting issue is **being taken care of** by Joseph.
>   **The** accounting issue was **taken care of** by Joseph.

or

> Accounting issues are taken care **of** by Joseph.